# Windows Workflow Foundation application (persistent) Server migration

Tags: .net, migration, workflow-foundation, database-migration

I’m doing a migration of a Windows Workflow Foundation application

**From**: Windows server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.0 Framework .Net 4.5 Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5

**To**: Windows 2012 server with IIS 8.0.9 Framework .Net 4.5 Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5

When I try to proceed with the execution of an instance of a running(migrated) process I got this error:

> The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance key [GUID] was not associated to an Instance

The process instance’s GUID of the error doesn’t match with the one present in the database.
It seems like that the process instance’s GUID is generated and not read from the database, but is generated with some data retrieved somewhere that changes with the new server.

Someone succeed on a migration of a Windows Workflow Foundation application with open instances of processes solving this problem?

thanks in advance,
Danny

Answer (score 0):

Danny.
We did this migration (with two difference - not from IIS 7.0, but from IIS 7.5, and our hosting is AppFabric) and really we didn't found any problem in it at all(although there is no any blog entry on this topic, what disappointed me). We have many thousands of active instances.

So my recommendation:
1. Check if old server is shut down. If not, I recommend to do it.
2. Try to find instance with this ID in persistence database.
If you use AppFabric:
1. Open Dashboard, check for errors.
2. Try to find instance with this ID in persistence db using dashboard.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Nickos, thanks for your response!
In your case the new server name was the same of the old one?

Comment: Hi, Danny! No, server has different name (and I might think, that server name does not realy matter). What is important is a IIS site name. You can see in persistence database, table ServiceDeploymentsTable - if site name is incorrect (or RelativeService/RelativeAppication path), you may have problems - change it in your IIS Also I strongly recommend not to change anything in this DB, for saving your nerves.